# Caching wrapper with multi-providers and factory to detect the responsible cache provider related to Type

Tags: c#, .net, cache, abstract-factory

***What I'm trying to do***

- abstract the caching actual cache provider (memory || distributed || ...).
- enable a caching diversity. each `cached item type` has different behavior.
- simply add more than one cache provider. and decide what provider to use with each cached record type based on configuration and settings

***there are several layers***

- abstracted cache
- cache factory (collect and detect the providers)
- cache providers
- cache implementation (e.g. `MemoryCache`)

```
    interface ICache
        {
            T Get<T>(string key);
            T Set<T>(string key, T value);
        }

    interface ICacheProvider
        {
            ICache Get();
        }
```

Cache factory and providers store

```
    public class CacheFactory
    {
        public ICache GetOrCreate<T>() => CacheProviderExtensions.GetProvider<T>().Get();
    }

    public static class CacheProviderExtensions
    {
        private const string DefaultCacheProvider = "DefaultCacheProvider";
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, ICacheProvider> providers = new();
        public static ICacheProvider GetProvider() => providers[DefaultCacheProvider];
        public static ICacheProvider GetProvider<T>() => providers[DefaultCacheProvider];
        public static void AddProvider(ICacheProvider provider) => providers.Add(DefaultCacheProvider, provider);
        public static void AddProvider<T>(ICacheProvider provider) => providers.Add(nameof(T), provider);
    }
```

abstracted implementation

```
    public class Cache : ICache
    {
        private readonly CacheFactory cacheFactory;
        public T Get<T>(string key) => cacheFactory.GetOrCreate<T>().Get<T>(key);
        public T Set<T>(string key, T value) => cacheFactory.GetOrCreate<T>().Set<T>(key, value);
    }
```

sample

```
    public class DictionaryMemoryCache : ICache
    {
        readonly Dictionary<string, object> cache = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public T Get<T>(string key) => (T)cache[key];
        public T Set<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            cache[key] = value;
            return value;
        }
    }

    public class CustomCache : ICache
    {
        public T Get<T>(string key) => default; //some-logic ...
        public T Set<T>(string key, T value) => default; //some-logic ...
    }

    public class DictionaryMemoryCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
    {
        public ICache Get() => new DictionaryMemoryCache();
    }
    public class CustomCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
    {
        public ICache Get() => new CustomCache();
    }
```

registration

```
    public class ConfigureStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<ICache, Cache>();
            services.AddSingleton<CacheFactory>();

            CacheProviderExtensions.AddProvider(new DictionaryMemoryCacheProvider());
            CacheProviderExtensions.AddProvider<Any>(new CustomCacheProvider());
        }
    }
```

issues:

- does it needs this implementation, is there a simpler way?
- I'm looking to replace the provider registration to rely on the .net DI

Comment: why you didn't use the existing cache solutions such as `MemoryCache` or `DistributedCache` ? what does your solution solve and offer over them ? Perhaps if you share a brief explanation on the dilemma that drove you to implement this, it would add more value to the question, and also would help the community for providing a better answer.

Comment: @iSR5  is a try to abstract the actual cache provider (memory || distributed || ...).
and enable a caching diversity each `cached item type` has different behavior.